# Initializing an array javascript, angular controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
myModule.controller('MetadataController', function () {
        this.allOrganisations = [{name:"test"}, {name:"alpha"}, {name:"beta"}];
        var arrayLength = this.allOrganisations.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
            alert(this.allOrganisations[i].name);
        }
});
```

is working, but in the view nothing coming out ?

```
<form name="form" novalidate ng-controller="MetadataController"  class="form-inline">
    <select ng-model="form.metadata.title.organisation" ng-options="organisation.name for organisation in form.AllOrganisations"></select><br>
    <ul >
      <li ng-repeat="o in form.allOrganisations">{{ o.name }}</li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Put `this` on line 3?

Comment: @Peteyeah typo, have edited

Comment: Change `this` to `$scope` and add `$scope` to the function signature.

Comment: Also remove `form` before allOrganisations in your view.

Answer (score 0):

Please see here http://jsbin.com/wewiv/1/

```
  myModule.controller('MetadataController', function ($scope) {
            $scope.allOrganisations = [{name:"test"}, {name:"alpha"}, {name:"beta"}];
            var arrayLength = $scope.allOrganisations.length;
            for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
                alert($scope.allOrganisations[i].name);
            }
    });
```

HTML:

```
 <select ng-model="form.metadata.title.organisation" ng-options="organisation.name for organisation in allOrganisations"></select><br>
    <ul >
      <li ng-repeat="o in allOrganisations">{{ o.name }}</li>
    </ul>
      </div>
```